# Excel Conditional Number Formatting In Charts

Tags: excel, charts, number-formatting, conditional-formatting

I am working with Excel 2010 and I want to apply conditional number formatting to value labels in a chart. When I apply the conditional formatting to the cells within the workbook, the conditional formatting works just fine, but when I feed that data to a chart the conditional number formatting is lost on the value labels.

A link to my screen shot can be found [here.](http://tinypic.com/r/35lx0cx/6) (I need more exp points to post a pic)

I am using the conditional formatting feature with three separate rules that are based on the value of a separate cell. I need the number formatting in the charts to automatically update (ie. no macros). I am aware that a cell can have conditions built into its custom number format, but it seems that the conditions can be based only on the value of the cell itself.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated and please ask if you need any more detail. I will be following this pretty closely over the next 72 hours.

M

Comment: You say  `... number formatting in the charts to automatically update (ie. no macros)`  What about using `Events`?  This may allow you to format the chart in responce to certain things happening in the sheet.  As you have discovered, conditional formatting and cell formatting affect a cell itself, not other objects that reference it.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the reccomendation. I will explore this as a possibility, but that could get ugly/complicated based on my use case. Is there any way I can put conditional number formatting with the cell's NumberFormat property or another possible solutuion?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question on stackoverflow, excelforum.com and my work forum and emailing experts such as the creator of the XY Value Label Add-In for Excel, I have confirmed that this is not possible to do directly. Number formatting for chart value labels does not link back to the conditional number formatting in the cell even if LinkNumberFormat = True. There is also not a way to pragmatically access chart value labels even even though I specified in my criteria VBA was not an option.

That leaves me (and anyone else with the same problem) with two options

1. I could change the original cell's number format either manually or pragmatically
   or
2. I could point the value labels at a separate cell that uses the text function and if statements to create the string that represents the value label. This cell would then automatically update and thus the value labels would as well.

Hopefully this will be updated in future releases of Excel :(